# What is the right way to handle Embedded Resources on a Razor View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, embedded-resource

I'm migrating some code from the ASPX view engine to Razor and I've run up onto a roadblock.

I have this code:

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="
    <%=Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl
        (typeof(DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.OpenIdSelector), 
        "DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.OpenIdSelector.css")%>" />
```

The problem here is that with Razor, I have no Page property.

So I took a step back for a second, and I'm looking at this wondering: What is the right way to get embedded resources in Razor?

I've spent a good bit of time trying to find solutions on this subject, but I haven't really found anything other than "wrap a new Page in a helper"

Is that the only way to do it? Or is there something more correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately the web resources are quite tied to the webforms infrastructure and it is difficult to reuse them without it. So a bit hacky but you could write a helper:

```
public static class UrlExtensions
{
    public static string WebResource(this UrlHelper urlHelper, Type type, string resourcePath)
    {
        var page = new Page();
        return page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(type, resourcePath);
    }
}
```

and in your razor view:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.WebResource(typeof(DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.OpenIdSelector), "DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.OpenIdSelector.css")" />
```

Another possibility is to write a custom HTTP handler/controller which will read the embedded resource from the assembly and stream it to the response by setting the proper content type.

Comment: which one would be better in this case?

Comment: @Adeel, I never use embedded CSS or javascript, so I don't have enough experience with this to tell which would be better. I suppose that reusing the WebForms's webresources will take care of things like caching, etc... so it might be better.

Answer (score 1):

Beside invoking `new Page()...` you can directly call the underlying implementation. Place this code in some static class:

```
public static string GetWebResourceUrl(this Assembly assembly, string name)
{ if (GetWebResourceUrlInternal == null)
  GetWebResourceUrlInternal = (Func<Assembly,string,bool,bool,System.Web.UI.ScriptManager,string>)
    typeof(System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader)
      .GetMethod("GetWebResourceUrlInternal", BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Static, null,
        new[]{typeof(Assembly),typeof(string),typeof(bool),typeof(bool),typeof(System.Web.UI.ScriptManager)}, null)
      .CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<Assembly,string,bool,bool,System.Web.UI.ScriptManager,string>));
  return GetWebResourceUrlInternal(assembly, name, false, false, null);
}
volatile static Func<Assembly,string,bool,bool,System.Web.UI.ScriptManager,string> GetWebResourceUrlInternal = null;
```

And in the Razor view or code behind use:

```
typeof(SomeClassInTheSameAssembly).Assembly.GetWebResourceUrl("Namespace.Resource.xxx")
```

Of course, using WebResource URLs in Razor views is not very useful. Instead it is recommended to place the resource into the Content or Scripts folder of your MVC application directly.

But the situation changes if you want to write `HtmlHelper` *functions in shared class libraries* which cannot place content into the target project.

---

### Rationale

This approach basically avoids to create a new, bulky `Page` object on each invocation of `GetWebResourceUrl`.

Looking at the [reference source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/UI/ClientScriptManager.cs,b9056070f6e07c80) it turns out that the `Page` and `ScriptManager` context is used just for nothing. So invoking `AssemblyResourceLoader.GetWebResourceUrlInternal` directly will hit the nail on the head. **All you need** to create a working WebResource.axd URL **is the Assembly** and, of course, **the resource name**.

The drawback is that this function is *internal*, so it have to be invoked by reflection. However, the above implementation avoids the overhead of calling the function by reflection every time. Instead `CreateDelegate` is used once to get an ordinary delegate which can be called almost without overhead.

The race condition at the access of field `GetWebResourceUrlInternal` is intended. It does not cause any significant harm because it is very unlikely to run into this code fragment with many parallel threads at the first invocation, and even if it happens the result is still reliable.