# GetWebResourceUrl equivalent for ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webresource.axd

In the old days of ASP.NET, one could use Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl to get a URL that would extract an embedded resource via the WebResource.axd HttpHandler.

In MVC, there doesn't seem to be ClientScript (or Page, for that matter). I can't find something comparable to this. I scoured MSDN, and I even googled it on bing and didn't find much.

Although I could certainly write this functionality and perhaps have a /Scripts/ controller - I wanted to see if there was a direct equivalent or preferred pattern on how to implement this functionality. Thanks

Comment: What view engine are you using aspx or Razor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the right way to handle Embedded Resources on a Razor View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996522/what-is-the-right-way-to-handle-embedded-resources-on-a-razor-view)

Answer (score 8):

Take a look  [ASP.NET MVC - Extracting Web Resources](http://www.eworldui.net/blog/post/2008/05/13/ASPNET-MVC-Extracting-Web-Resources.aspx), hope this helps.

Comment: [Rick Strahl](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Jul/30/WebResource-access-in-ASPNET-MVC) also has a good post on the topic (offers methods that do not trudge into reflection).