# Trying to retrieve an embedded resource in asp.net

Tags: .net, asp.net, embedded-resource

I am trying to retrieve the **ResourceStyle.css** embedded resource by using the **Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl()** method. However, I receive a 404 resource not found error when I try to browse to the url that GetWebResourceUrl() returns.

I have already set the build action for ResourceStyle.css to Embedded Resource and added the [assembly: WebResource()] attribute in the Default.aspx.cs file.

I have uploaded the project to [github](https://github.com/paulyoder/WebResourceExample). If you know how to resolve this issue, please [fork the repository](https://github.com/paulyoder/WebResourceExample) and make the necessary changes and then send me a pull request. Look at the Default.aspx.cs file for the pertinent code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GetWebResourceUrl() requires two arguments, a type and the name of the embedded resource. I was using this.GetType() as the first argument, but GetType() doesn't work if the class uses inheritance. I used typeof() instead of now it works.

```
Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(typeof(_Default), "WebResources.Styles.ResourceStyle.css");
```

Comment: checkout this question for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745819/using-embedded-webresources-throughout-webresource-axd